# Hide 'View Entries' if the field is blank - Multiple lines of Text Append Changes

Tags: list-view, column, jslink, rendering, multiple-lines-of-text

I have a 'Multiple lines of text' field on a custom list that has 'Append Changes' enabled. My client would like to hide the 'View Entries' link (in the List View) if there is nothing in the field. It currently shows the link regardless if the field has entries or not.

Is there a way to hide this 'View Entries' link if the field is null? I'm thinking I can process the field using JSLink but I would have to query the list everytime to see if there are entries.. Any suggestions?

Comment: It would have to be done with client code. jQuery/javascript as there is no other way to check it. Do all the links just show up and you can only tell when you click them that they are empty.

Comment: Yes, I can only tell by clicking into the list item. The user doesn't want to click if the field is empty

Comment: Bummer. Yes, those are tough because you have to write some function to check it. The problem is that the field may not be "empty" but have an empty div tag in it. That is where, it may need to be decided to use an XSLT list view to display the data instead because that can be tested.